# (How) did the South African rabbinate deal with non-white conversion candidates during apartheid?

Tags: history, conversion-to-judaism, beit-din-court, dina-dmalchusa-dina

As I understand it, during apartheid, the South African government treated the Jews as "white."

Did it ever happen that someone in a different racial group expressed interest in converting to Judaism in South Africa? Could the rabbis have converted them without running afoul of the apartheid laws? Would the synagogue then need different bathrooms for different races? How did this play out?

Comment: To the close voter: This is asking about the history of how Halacha was practiced, which IMO makes it history of Judaism, not Jews or Jewish culture, and therefore on-topic.

Comment: You sould rewrite the question to make it clearer about the halacha. Additionally, it is a matter of resisting improper laws. Also the question would apply to born Jews such as Ethiopean Jews or other *races* born Jewish.

Comment: @DonielF It appears to me that the question is purely historical/political. it also has 4 different questions

Comment: @AlBerko Yes, but there are no close votes as too broad, only off-topic. Do you not see how the question is asking about the historical interplay of Halacha and politics?

Comment: @DonielF You're right, it's a matter of wording. If the question was "how was halachic decisions affected by the regime?" I'd pass, but  the question focuses on the historical practice, not theory.

Comment: @AlBerko Historical practice isn’t necessarily off-topic if it’s about Judaism as a way of life, which this is.

Comment: @DonielF Interesting, when one VTCs he does not mark his level of assurance. Seriously I don't care so much, I just pointed that for me the question was historical, more about the regime than Judaism. Does it really matter?

Comment: Not that this answers the question as stated, (and as stated it IS off topic), but why would the Beis Din have to accept such a convert? We always try to discourage a potential convert at first; and if it would be hard for the community, I think they can give a simple no. Correct me if I'm wrong.